# Showing Duplicate entry for same item in Cart

Tags: php, magento

I am writing Magento ecommerce portal in which i am allowing user to buy a product with different-2 sizes (like: small, large, xl, xxl) but i am facing a small issue, whenever i adding same item for different-2 sizes in cart, it also showing same item image for all sizes in cart.

for an example: Item name : Killer Jeans, available sizes: 32. 36 and 40 width

now whenever i do tap on size 32 it showing me killer jeans image in cart, with size i selected, again i select size 36 it showing me in cart you selected Killer Jeans for size 32 and 36 which is exactly i need, but the issue is same Killer Jeans image showing twice which is not right.

so what could be the reason?

please check below php script:

```
<?php
    $categoryIds = array(17);//category id

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                                 ->getCollection()
                                 ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds)) 
?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $collection->count() ?>
    <?php // $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; $j=1; foreach ($collection as $product): ?>
        <?php if($j>3) break; ?>
        <?php if ($i++%3==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $product->getName()?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(197, 167); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName()?>" border="0" />
                    </a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $product->getName()?>"><?php echo $product->getName() ?></a></h2>
               <div class="price-box">
               <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(),true,false);?>
               </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/')?>product/<?php echo $product->getId() ?>/')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Buy');?>" type="submit"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy');?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $j++ ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>

<?php // endif; ?>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understand you correctly - but I assume you want to display in cart just one image for SIMPLE product, even when another SIMPLE product from the same CONFIGURABLE is added to cart?

If yes - then imho you should just modify the way you present data in the cart not the way you add products to cart. And the